# Compose: TopAppBar default height for Material3?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, material3

How can I find out the default height for the SmallTopAppBar (or just TopAppBar)? I am implementing a SearchView that replaces the topBar with a similar looking bar with the Search TextView but I cant find out how to apply the proper height.

In TopAppBarDefaults:

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/TopAppBarDefaults

only the color is shown.

Answer (score 1):

It's `64dp`, you can find that in [`TopAppBarSmallTokens`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/7b27816c561b8f271d79d24ab21ba7d08aaad031:compose/material3/material3/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/tokens/TopAppBarSmallTokens.kt;l=26) and in [material design docs](https://m3.material.io/components/top-app-bar/specs).

Comment: YEa but Id like to assing the value semantically straight from the theme rather than hardcode it directly. But I see all the values are private...